# How to override subscriber in Shopware 6?

Tags: symfony, shopware

I would like to override a plugin's event subscriber. Is it possible by just adjusting the priority in the service.xml?

Are there any other ways to disable a subscriber?

Comment: In my opinion, you can try to create your own subscriber for the same event but with higher priority. And call `$event->stopPropagation()` inside it to prevent execution of further subscribers. But it is just an assumption and i didn't check it.

Comment: @ValeriiPravoslavnyi This might cause problems with other subscribers on the same event. It is intented to only override the single plugin's event subscriber.

Comment: @Alex you a right. Probably decorating of plugin's subscriber is a better option.

Comment: It is possible to remove services via a compile pass also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393662/how-to-remove-a-service-definition-in-symfony2

Comment: But I would not recommend the compile pass - sounds a bit too complicated / overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disabled the subscriber by decorating it.
That way I could simply add a new `getSubscribedEvents()` function, that returns an empty array.

see:
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/adjusting-service

Answer (score 1):

Subscribers are also normal symfony services, so a simple decorating of the service should work.
Create your own subscriber and add to it's DI declaration the "decorates" attribute with the class name of the original subscriber as value.

Comment: Sounds like an option, but might cause problems if the original service's protected methods should be overwritten, as decoration works only on public methods. Isn't there a way to disable a service via service.xml ?

Comment: We found a nice & clean solution using this approach, MweisIMI will post :-)